# Combine values with Java8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, rx-java

If I have a list with integers, is there a way to construct another list, where integers are summed if the difference to the head of the new list is below a threashold? I would like to solve this using Java 8 streams. It should work similar to the [Scan operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html) of RxJava.

```
Example: 5, 2, 2, 5, 13    
Threashold: 2    
Result: 5, 9, 13

Intermediate results:    
5
5, 2
5, 4 (2 and 2 summed)
5, 9 (4 and 5 summed)
5, 9, 13
```

Comment: You can perform the scan operator quite easy using [`Arrays.parallelPrefix(array, Integer::sum)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelPrefix-int:A-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-). But what you want to do doesn’t look like the scan operator…

Comment: I did already solved it with the scan operator with something like `(x, y) -> (abs(x-y<2)) ? x+y : y`

Comment: Then you have a “solution”. Besides that your description says you want to have a result list of a different size than the original one and the scan operator doesn’t do that…

Comment: I would like to solve it with Java 8 streams, if possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sequential Stream solution may look like this:

```
List<Integer> result = Stream.of(5, 2, 2, 5, 13).collect(ArrayList::new, (list, n) -> {
    if(!list.isEmpty() && Math.abs(list.get(list.size()-1)-n) < 2)
        list.set(list.size()-1, list.get(list.size()-1)+n);
    else
        list.add(n);
}, (l1, l2) -> {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();});
System.out.println(result);
```

Though it looks not much better as good old solution:

```
List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(5, 2, 2, 5, 13);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(Integer n : input) {
    if(!list.isEmpty() && Math.abs(list.get(list.size()-1)-n) < 2)
        list.set(list.size()-1, list.get(list.size()-1)+n);
    else
        list.add(n);
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Seems that your problem is not associative, so it cannot be easily parallelized. For example, if you split the input into two groups like this `(5, 2), (2, 5, 13)`, you cannot say whether the first two items of the second group should be merged until the first group is processed. Thus I cannot specify the proper combiner function.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you. One question: What is the purpose of the `combiner` function and why it is not going to be called in this case?

Comment: @Artjom, combiner is used for parallel streams to combine two partial results together. Here we use sequential stream, so it's not called.

Answer (score 4):

As [Tagir Valeev observed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32070250/1441122), (+1) the combining function is not associative, so `reduce()` won't work, and it's not possible to write a combiner function for a `Collector`. Instead, this combining function needs to be applied left-to-right, with the previous partial result being fed into the next operation. This is called a **fold-left** operation, and unfortunately Java streams don't have such an operation.

(Should they? Let me know.)

It's possible to sort-of write your own fold-left operation using `forEachOrdered` while capturing and mutating an object to hold partial state. First, let's extract the combining function into its own method:

```
// extracted from Tagir Valeev's answer
void combine(List<Integer> list, int n) {
    if (!list.isEmpty() && Math.abs(list.get(list.size()-1)-n) < 2)
        list.set(list.size()-1, list.get(list.size()-1)+n);
    else
        list.add(n);
}
```

Then, create the initial result list and call the combining function from within `forEachOrdered`:

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.of(5, 2, 2, 5, 13)
         .forEachOrdered(n -> combine(result, n));
```

This gives the desired result of

```
[5, 9, 13]
```

In principle this can be done on a parallel stream, but performance will probably degrade to sequential given the semantics of `forEachOrdered`. Also note that the `forEachOrdered` operations are performed one at a time, so we needn't worry about thread safety of the data we're mutating.

Comment: By the way, I'm looking forward for [stream.foldLeft()](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8133680) feature in JDK 9! You can even take [my code](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/a1290a4b55074e0696f3e49d23b6961bd5681034/src/main/java/javax/util/streamex/AbstractStreamEx.java#L995) :-) It's actually useful.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 way is define custom IntSpliterator class:

```
static class IntThreasholdSpliterator extends Spliterators.AbstractIntSpliterator {
    private PrimitiveIterator.OfInt it;
    private int threashold;
    private int sum;

    public IntThreasholdSpliterator(int threashold, IntStream stream, long est) {
        super(est, ORDERED );
        this.it = stream.iterator();
        this.threashold = threashold;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(IntConsumer action) {
        if(!it.hasNext()){
            return false;
        }
        int next = it.nextInt();
        if(next<threashold){
            sum += next;
        }else {
            action.accept(next + sum);
            sum = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }

}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    IntThreasholdSpliterator s = new IntThreasholdSpliterator(3, IntStream.of(5, 2, 2, 5, 13), 5);
    List<Integer> rs= StreamSupport.intStream(s, false).mapToObj(Integer::valueOf).collect(toList());
    System.out.println(rs);
}
```

Also you can hack it as

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5, 2, 2, 5, 13);
    int[] sum = {0};
    list = list.stream().filter(s -> {
        if(s<=2) sum[0]+=s;
        return s>2;
    }).map(s -> {
        int rs = s + sum[0];
        sum[0] = 0;
        return rs;
    }).collect(toList());
    System.out.println(list);
```

But I am not sure that this hack is good idea for production code.

Comment: Since you don’t know the number of elements, your spliterator should not report to be `SIZED`. By the way, there is no need to implement `characteristics()`, you already inherit a `characteristics()` method which will return the characteristics you have specified in the super constructor call.

Comment: Thanks I remove `characteristics`.  Original post says: _I have a list with integers_ so we know size of stream.

Comment: You may know the size of the original list, but your spliterator conditionally sums some of the elements up, reducing the size of the resulting stream in an unpredictable manner. Hence, the original spliterator might be `SIZED` but yours is not. Note that you still have `SIZED` in your constructor.

Comment: I doubt that Java-8 way is to define custom spliterator for each non-trivial task. Spliterator is considered as quite low-level feature...

Comment: @Holger  yes you are right. I removed SIZED from constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the Stream's masters "Tagir Valeev" and "Stuart Marks" already pointed out that reduce() will not work because the combining function is not associative, and I'm risking a couple of downvotes here. Anyway:

What about if we force the stream to be sequential? Wouldn't we be able then to use reduce? Isn't the associativity property only needed when using parallelism?

```
    Stream<Integer> s = Stream.of(5, 2, 2, 5, 13);
    LinkedList<Integer> result =  s.sequential().reduce(new LinkedList<Integer>(), 
                 (list, el) -> { 
                     if (list.isEmpty() || Math.abs(list.getLast() - el) >= 2) {
                         list.add(el);
                     } else {
                         list.set(list.size() - 1, list.getLast() + el);
                     }
                     return list; 
                 }, (list1, list2) -> {
                         //don't really needed, as we are sequential
                         list1.addAll(list2); return list1;
                      });
```

Comment: Actually Stuart Marks answer shows how to solve this even for parallel streams. In his solution the upstream operations (if any) can still be parallelized. In your particular case adding `.sequential()` is unnecessary as [`Stream.of`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-) is guaranteed to return a sequential stream.

Comment: @TagirValeev Thanks Tagir! That your answer and Stuart's are correct is out of discussion. My question was: If we assume that the Stream is sequential, could we write a reduce() operation with an accumulator function that is not associative? i.e. is the associative property only required for parallel streams?

Comment: In practice you can, but in theory you cannot, because the documentation [explicitly says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) that accumulator function must be associative. Hopefully with [foldLeft](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8133680) introduction there will be a legal way to do this (read this bug description for details).

Comment: This solution is broken regardless of the associativity as it violates the other contract of `reduce` that it *must not* manipulate the value objects. What you are doing is *mutable reduction*, thus you should use `collect` instead of `reduce`. Besides that, there is no reason to use `LinkedList` here. It offers no benefit but just additional overhead. In fact, it’s hard to find a use case for `LinkedList` anywhere…

Comment: @Holger Thanks. I know that the solution is not a valid one; i just wanted to know if the "associativity" rule only applies for parallel streams, and Tagir has already answered it. As you point out, the "stateless" property of the accumulator is also broken, but, from my point of view, this doesn't apply (in practice) to sequential streams. Regarding LinkedList: it was used just for readability: getLast() is more intuitive than get(l.size()-1).